# MVC 4, jTable 2.3, Table data isn't rebuilt on second (+) call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jtable

A selection on the first table results in change in the second table. However, the change occurs only once. Any subsequent calls do generate valid JSON but the html remains unchanged.

The Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult M1List(int jtStartIndex, int jtPageSize, string jtSorting)
    {
        try
        {
            List<tblM> m1 = new DataHelper().GetM1(jtSorting, jtPageSize, jtStartIndex);
            int m1Count = new DataHelper().Getm1Count();

            return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = m1, TotalRecordCount = m1Count });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult M2List(int mId, int jtStartIndex, int jtPageSize)
    {
        try
        {
            List<ViewM1A> m2 = new DataHelper().GetM2ForM1(mId.ToString(), "mId", jtPageSize, jtStartIndex);
            int m2Count = new DataHelper().GetM2ForM1Count(mId.ToString());

            return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = m2, TotalRecordCount = m2Count });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#m1TC').jtable({
        paging: true,
        sorting: true,
        defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
        selecting: true, //Enable selecting
        multiselect: false, //Allow multiple selecting
        actions: {
            listAction: '@Url.Action("M1List")'
        },
        fields: {
            mId: {
                title: 'Id'
            }
        },
        selectionChanged: function () {
            var $selectedRows = $('#m1TC').jtable('selectedRows');
            $selectedRows.each(function () {
                var record = $(this).data('record');
                buildM2Table(record.mId);
            });
            $('#m2TC').jtable('load');
        }
    });
    $('#m1TC').jtable('load');
});

function buildM2Table(actionUrl) {
    $('#m2TC').jtable({
        paging: true,
        sorting: true,
        defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
        selecting: true, //Enable selecting
        multiselect: true, //Allow multiple selecting
        selectingCheckboxes: true, //Show checkboxes on first column
        actions: {
            listAction: '/Connections/M2List?mId=' + actionUrl
        },
        fields: {
            FullName: {
                title: 'Name'
            },

        },
        selectionChanged: function () {
            var $selectedRows = $('#m2TC').jtable('selectedRows');

            $('#SelectedRowList').empty();
            if ($selectedRows.length > 0) {
            } else {
                $('#SelectedRowList').append('No row selected! Select rows to see here...');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The html:

```
<div id="m1TC"></div>
<div id="m2TC"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding this code after 'var record = $(this).data("record");':

```
$('#m2TC').remove();
$('#m1TC').after('<div id="m2TC"></div>');
```